# 'TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')'----Array assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

When I was solving a problem on Leetcode, I've defined an empty array.  I tried push some numbers  then I got this Error. I don't know why. My code here.

```
        // r and c are already defined numbers，arr is already defined array.
        let n = [[]]
        let index = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    n[i][j] = arr[index]
                    index++;
            }
        }
        return n;
```

Leetcode told me    n[i][j] = arr[index] had error；

Anyone knows why? thanks.

Comment: Here n[i][j] = arr[index] tries to get the element with index i and then assign the element of the inner array with the arr element. The problem is that your n array has only one element and hence n[i] is undefined where variable i is greater than 0

Comment: @Tanay thanks！ I tried creating  new Array to push some numbers ,then push Array to n . Now I can get the right two-dimensional array N. My code got ACCEPT！ thanks you again！ Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the value of i becomes 1, inside the inner loop it is setting the value to n[i][j], which is n[1][0], here n[1] is undefined and it is accessing the 0th index value of undefined, that is the reason of the error.

the first iteration works fine because there is already an empty array in the 0th index (when i = 0).

here you can try doing this

```
let n = []
let index = 0
for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    n[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        n[i][j] = arr[index];
        index++;
    }
}

return n;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments showed, it is possible to use .push.
This is how I implemented that solution in my case.

```
const myArray = [[]];
const height = 7;
const width = 8;

for (let i= 0; i < height; i++) {

    if (i> 0) myArray.push([]); // this initialises the array.
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = "x";
    }

}

console.log(myArray)
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/andreasaanestad/pen/jOzqbOX?editors=1112)